# Is there a way to process Karma - Angular unit tests in batches?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

We are facing an issue where our tests will start failing or running extremely slow after a certain point. I have seen articles online where others too are facing issues. The primary reason for those failures are memory consumed by browsers while we deal with DOM.
We are using seed project which builds our application using SystemJS. Our Current version of Angular is 2.2.3.

So, I am thinking of a work around where I can either parallel process our test runs (i.e. multiple karma server running, I did try that but it starts to consume 100% CPU) or batch processing. So, batches of small test runs which will ensure that karma is stopped and started again.

Is there a way?

Also, if we are able to achieve that, how to get a consistent coverage? We are using istanbul.

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

e.g. our service and model related tests run in 3 seconds (500+ tests) but our component tests (900+) take 15 **mins**.

Comment: Our team also has an interest in a test sharding feature. There's an open issue in the Karma backlog but it's old and seems to have lost momentum. https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/439

Comment: yes, I have seen that thread. Didn't help much. May be if this question gets enough votes, it reaches some ears.

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty good plugin for Karma that allows sharding tests and executing them in parallel - https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel
We have integrated it in both AngularJS & Angular 4 & 5 projects.
With code-base with more than 2000 tests it is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Karma Parallel hasn't been maintained in the interim 5 years. I didn't try it because it now contains insecure packages. Thought I would post my solution for anyone struggling with the same memory issues.

I used `ng test`'s `--include` flag to split the application's tests into groups. So now I have a scripts config that looks something like this.

```
{
    "name": "my-application",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --configuration production",
        "test-group-one": "ng test --include src/app/tool-one",
        "test-group-two": "ng test --include src/app/tool-two",
        "test-group-three": "ng test --include src/app/!(tool-one|tool-two)"
    }
}
```

This does require you to manually define segments of you application but the glob patterns allow for alot of flexiblity. For example you could run all the service unit tests with `*.service.spec.ts` if you wanted to group by type instead of folder.

This solution doesn't require third party libraries and uses standard Angular features. You can run the groups sequentially or concurrently allowing for more stability or more performance.

Hope this helps someone in the same situation.